# MetaMask: white screen in chrome

Tags: metamask

This is an incredibly annoying issue. I cannot get into MetaMask in chrome, the screen won't pop up and instead shows white space. The plugin console does not throw any error. I have tried restarting metamask, restarting Chrome, but it all doesn't work.

On Firefox it works, so it appears that there is no connection issue.

Any idea how to fix this, or where to look at?

Edit: this still is an issue. (Will only use bump once)

Comment: I had the same problem last week.


`contentscript.js:1 MetamaskContentscript - lost connection to MetaMask Contentscript Forwarding
s @ contentscript.js:1
contentscript.js:1 MetamaskContentscript - lost connection to MetaMask Inpage
s @ contentscript.js:1
contentscript.js:1 MetamaskContentscript - lost connection to MetaMask Background
s @ contentscript.js:1
contentscript.js:1 MetamaskContentscript - lost connection to MetaMask PingPongStream`

That is what I saw in my console. I had to reinstall my metamask.

Comment: You can try asking in https://gitter.im/MetaMask/Lobby. 
Dan Finlay (Lead developer Metamask) sent me to this: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/new

By that time I had already reinstalled my Metamask because I was in a hurry. Maybe he, or someone else is able to help you.